# Crop video random with time variables (t) with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, crop

I want to crop video with x and y coordinates that change with time (t) or frame (n). Which mathematical expression should I use

I used:

crop=in_w/2:in_h/2:(in_w-out_w)/2+((in_w-out_w)/2)*sin(t*10):(in_h-out_h)/2 +((in_h-out_h)/2)*sin(t*13)"

but it only changes diagonally

Comment: It depends entirely on what you want the animation to be.

Comment: This Animation. Can you help me @Gyan [Animation Crop Video](https://youtu.be/-rRAu2o4DFY)